# Better way to check element between getPageSource and webelement - selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

At first I used `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='xxx']"))` to find but I think it's too slow.

I think I'll use `getPageSource` after that use `indexOf()` to search from the text.

Which one is better?

Comment: How did you identify that _Its too slow_ ?

Comment: because when find element I have to wait for a few second to let it process.

Answer (score 0):

- I do not know why you think driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='xxx']")) is too slow. In my opinion, it is fast enough and I think findElement is better.
- If you apply Page Object Model or Screen Play, you must find element by the way driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='xxx']")) do.
- Page Object Model tutorial: https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='xxx']")) and its faster as well. You can use chropath tool to find the web elements on web page .You can find this tool in extensions of chrome browser.

Comment: I have 1 more question. I can't find element in object webelement. Thanks and sorry my english skill is low.

Comment: Didn't got your question properly . Can you please explain it in detail.

Comment: webelement a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='xxx']")) 
webelement b = a.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='zzz']")) 
how to get b.